# AutoFocus is not working after navigation

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have 2 screens let's say A and B,
A is for registering users and B is for getting more details about users (firstName, lastName etc.) When I navigate from screen A to B after submission, Keyboard doesn't open automatically for the first field of the screen which is firstName input field, even if the input field is clicked. But if I click on lastName input field or some other, the keyboard appears. And if I remove autoFocus from firstName input field, the keyboard doesn't open automatically but opens on click.

here's my code of the firstName input field

```
<TextInput
          autoFocus={true}
          ref={firstNameRef}
          style={[styles.input]}
          placeholder={''}
          value={firstName}
          onChangeText={setFirstName}
          autoCapitalize="none"
          autoCorrect={false}
          returnKeyType="next"
          onSubmitEditing={() => lastNameRef.current.focus()}
        />
```

I tried to focus firstName input field manually like this

```
useEffect(() => {
if (firstNameRef.current) {
  firstNameRef.current.focus();
}
}, []);
```

But still no luck :(

Comment: Have you tried use `useFocusEffect()` instead of `useEffect()`?

Comment: @MikołajWittbrodt yes, still not working